# MySQL table NOT NULL

Tags: mysql, database, null

I created a table in MySQL with the following code on CentOS 6.4 with MySQL 5.1

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  t1 int(10) NOT NULL,
  t2 varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (t1),
  UNIQUE KEY t2 (t2)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

But after the query is successfully executed.
The output of the `desc test` is

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| t1    | int(10)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| t2    | varchar(12) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

It's showing `DEFAULT` as `NULL` instead of `NOT NULL`.

But the results are same.

After this If a give an insert

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES ()
```

The insert is successful but it shouldn't be as i have given NULL values and t1 has 0 as the value.
The insert should fail as the value is NULL.

Subsequent inserts produce errors due to duplicate key clause.
Please tell me where I am going wrong.

I tried this on another machine with MySQL 5.5 on a Ubuntu 13.04 .

```
| Variable_name           | Value                   |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.5.32                  |
| protocol_version        | 10                      |
| slave_type_conversions  |                         |
| version                 | 5.5.32-0ubuntu0.13.04.1 |
| version_comment         | (Ubuntu)                |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                  |
| version_compile_os      | debian-linux-gnu        |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: On SQL Fiddle (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!8), the insert fails with the appropriate error message:  "Schema Creation Failed: Field 't1' doesn't have a default value".

Comment: @Gordon Linoff : I am not getting any error and the table is created successfully.
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!8/3536c/2/0

Comment: . . That is correct.  The default value is NULL even though that value is not allowed in the column.  The error comes when you try to insert the default.

Comment: In SQL Fiddle if you don't give the insert statement the table is created and after that you can give the insert which works fine on a SQL prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You have write, your table have 2 fields NOT nullable, but you dont' specify the default value for them. (In your third column output - NULL - you read NO)

I've rewrite your script with default value

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    t1 int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    t2 varchar(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (t1),
    UNIQUE KEY t2 (t2)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: I dont want to keep a default value.
Is it not necessary to keep default value  ?

Comment: Your INSERT statement goes in error. I try on my PC. The default value, IHMO, is necessary on the field not nullable to prevent error (link in your insert). I don't know why your INSERT complete with success.